# Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

We consider the family $$\mathcal{I}=\{(a,b)\;|\;-\infty<a<b<+\infty\}\cup\{[-\infty, b)\;|\;b\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(a,+\infty]\;|\;a\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

> I proved that $$\mathcal{B}\big(\overline{\mathbb{R}}\big)=\sigma_0\big(\mathcal{I}\big),$$ where $\sigma_0\big(\mathcal{I}\big)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{I}.$

---

> **What I would like to prove.** I would like to prove that $$\mathcal{B}\big(\overline{\mathbb{R}}\big)=\sigma_0\big(\mathcal{J}\big),$$ where $\mathcal{J}$ is the family $$\mathcal{J}=\big\{(a,+\infty]\;|\;a\in\mathbb{R}\big\}.$$

---

We observe that $\mathcal{J}\subseteq\mathcal{I}$, then $\sigma_0\big(\mathcal{J}\big)\subseteq\sigma_0\big(\mathcal{I}\big)=\mathcal{B}\big(\overline{\mathbb{R}}\big)$. Note that the inclusion $\sigma_0\big(\mathcal{J}\big)\subseteq\sigma_0\big(\mathcal{I}\big)$ is a conseguence of a proposition that I have already proved.

> **Question.** How can I prove that $$\mathcal{B}\big(\overline{\mathbb{R}}\big)\subseteq\sigma_0\big(\mathcal{J}\big).$$

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $[-\infty, b) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (b-\frac{1}{n}, \infty]$ for $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $[-\infty, \infty) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (n, \infty]$ are elements of $\sigma_0(\mathcal{J})$, and so, $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \sigma_0(\mathcal{J})$.

Comment: Thanks for hit, But having two questions: $\mathbb{R}\in\sigma_0\big(\mathcal{J}\big)$? if I write $(a,b)=(a,+\infty]\cap [-\infty,b)$, where do I use the fact that $[-\infty,+\infty)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(n,+\infty]$?

Comment: Oh, I thought that $\mathcal{I}$ should contain both $(-\infty, \infty]$ and $[-\infty, \infty)$. For the first question, we know that $(-n, n) = (-n, \infty] \cap [-\infty, n)$ are in $\sigma_o(\mathcal{J})$, and taking union of them shows that $\mathbb{R} \in \sigma_o(\mathcal{J})$.

Comment: Can I say that $\mathbb{R}=\overline{\mathbb{R}}\setminus\big[\{-\infty\}\cup\{+\infty\}\big]\in\sigma_0(\mathcal{J})$?

Comment: Is that question different from what you asked in your previous comment?

Comment: No. But If I write $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-n,+\infty]\cap[-\infty,n)$, to say that it is in $\sigma_0(\mathcal{J})$ I must say that $[-\infty,n)\in\sigma_0(\mathcal{J})$ coming back so far.

Comment: Although I made a notation mistake in the first place, I already showed in my first comment that $$[-\infty, b) = \overline{\mathbb{R}} \setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (b-\tfrac{1}{n}, \infty]$$ for each $b \in \mathbb{R}$, and notice that the right-hand side lies in $\sigma_o(\mathcal{J})$.